# Calculate mean over discrete functions with different amount of sampling points

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have a set of measurement curves (represented as an array of x and an array of y values). I need to calculate the average curve of this set. 
The curves in the set may vary both in number of sampling points (x-values) and position of the sampling points.

I first interpolate every curve linearly using scipys interp1d. I then determine the range of x-values where all curves overlap, in order for the interpolated functions to be defined. Finally i need to calculate the mean, this is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that your question is rather conceptual than coding related. However, the following example should help you:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# make up three datasets for testing
x1 = np.linspace(0, 10, num=11, endpoint=True)
x2 = np.linspace(0, 10, num=13, endpoint=True)
x3 = np.linspace(0, 10, num=23, endpoint=True)

y1 = np.cos(-x1**2/9.0) + 0.2*np.random.rand((len(x1)))
y2 = np.cos(-x2**2/9.0) + 0.2*np.random.rand((len(x2)))
y3 = np.cos(-x3**2/9.0) + 0.2*np.random.rand((len(x3)))

# interpolate data
f1 = interp1d(x1, y1,'cubic')
f2 = interp1d(x2, y2,'cubic')
f3 = interp1d(x3, y3,'cubic')

# define common carrier for calculation of average curve
x_all = np.linspace(0, 10, num=101, endpoint=True)

# evaluation of fits on common carrier
f1_int = f1(x_all)
f2_int = f2(x_all)
f3_int = f3(x_all)

# put all fits to one matrix for fast mean calculation
data_collection = np.vstack((f1_int,f2_int,f3_int))

# calculating mean value
f_avg = np.average(data_collection, axis=0)

# plot this example
plt.figure()
plt.hold('on')
plt.plot(x1,y1,'ro',label='row1')
plt.plot(x2,y2,'bo',label='row2')
plt.plot(x3,y3,'go',label='row3')

plt.plot(x_all,f1_int,'r-',label='fit1')
plt.plot(x_all,f2_int,'b-',label='fit2')
plt.plot(x_all,f3_int,'g-',label='fit3')

plt.plot(x_all, f_avg,'k--',label='fit average')
plt.legend(loc=3)

plt.hold('off')
plt.show()
```

The most important lines are those using `np.vstack` to combine the measurements and `np.average` to take the average of the measurements. The rest is just to have a working example!

EDIT: 
For nonequidistant carrier of the fits do e.g. the following:

```
# define common carrier for calculation of average curve
x_all_1 = np.linspace(0, 1, num=101, endpoint=True)
x_all_2 = np.linspace(1, 10, num=21, endpoint=True)
x_all = np.concatenate((x_all_1, x_all_2))
```

Comment: thank you jkalden. My problem now is that half of the datapoints may be in [0,1] and the rest maybe spread out on [1,10]. So naturally I don't want a evenly spaced linspace for x_all, but one that has more entries in [0,1] and fewer in [1,10].

Comment: You are free to choose the content of `x_all`! See my edit, but that's a new question... Once your question given above is answered satisfyingly, please mark the answer as accepted and ask new questions.

Comment: I'm sorry if I have not expressed myself clearly enough: the whole point of the question is to find a way to determine x_all. My comment above was just an example, I don't know beforehand how the sampling points are distributed in the data.

Comment: `x_all` does not depend on the sampling points of the measurements! It is just useful to only take averages in regions where your measurements have data, i.e. minimum and maximum of `x_all` should be chosen depending on the measurement sampling points. `f_avg` contains the mean at each sampling point of `x_all`...

Comment: yes and thats exactly the problem :) In my case it may be that if have 10 sampling points in [0,0.1], another one in [50,51], and maybe again 5 in [10000, 11000]. So if i just make a linspace(0,11000, num), num would have got to be ridiculously big to achieve suffienct resolution around 0.

Comment: and as I said, I don't know that distribution in advance, it could also be completely different

Comment: Then assemble your `x_all` as `x_all = np.concatenate((np.linspace(0,0.1,num=11, endpoint=True), np.linspace(50,51,num=6, endpoint=True), np.linspace(10000,11000,num=6, endpoint=True)))`. Did you try that? If you only have one measurement per x region, maybe 'mean' is misleading...

Comment: Ill give another example to illustrate my point. Those might be the sampling values (corresponding y-values left out) of 3 curves I want to calculate the mean over. In practice I might calculate the mean of a couple of hundred of curves.
 
[0.1, 0.15, 0.17, 0.18, 0.185, 20, 1000, 15000]
[0.09, 0.151, 0.169, 0.18, 21, 14000]
[0.11, 0.2, 13999, 14001]

In this particular example it would suffice to have among a sampling point at [0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 20, 1000, 14000, 15000]. I need to calculate that on the fly.

Comment: So, `x_all=np.array([0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 20, 1000, 14000, 15000])`. Are you asking for a generic rule to generate `x_all`? If so, you should ask a new question where this requirement is clearly visible.

Comment: yes, i'm looking for a generic rule. I'm not sure how I can improve the clarity of my question further. I already adressed in my original question how I attempted to solve my problem (histogram and pdf) and also stated in the final two paragraphs that I was mainly interested in finding those sample points. I admit that the original title may have been misleading though, but I have already changed that.

Comment: Editing the Title after receiving an answer is misleading aswell... Apart from that, I cannot retrieve the requirements for the sampling points from your question, nor can I from your given example...

Comment: fair enough, if it is allright with you I will reedit my question so that it matches your answer and open a new one for my actual question.